# Js, what is 'this' when set the static function from a Class to variable object

Tags: javascript, class, this

```js
class Obj {
  static log(){
    console.log(this)
  }
}

var test = Obj.log

Obj.log() // class Obj
test() // undefined
```

This is the code I run **without** 'use strict'. The result I don't understand. Why does the function `test` log `undefined` instead of the global object?

Comment: What did you expect it to return?

Comment: The window object like the simple function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `class` code is **always** strict code. From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-class-definitions)

> NOTE     A class definition is always strict code.

Since `class` code is always strict, the method `log` is a strict function (so amongst other things, its internal [[ThisMode]] slot is set to `strict`), and when you call a strict function without setting `this`, `this` is set to `undefined` for the call.

The chain of operations in the spec that sets this up is that a direct call expression [is evaluated](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-evaluatecall) by eventually calling the spec's abstract [EvaluateDirectCall](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-evaluatedirectcall) operation with *thisValue* set to `undefined`. That in turn calls [Call](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-call) passing along the *thisValue*, which calls [[[Call]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) on the function passing *thisValue* as *thisArgument*, which calls [OrdinaryCallBindThis](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ordinarycallbindthis), which checks the function's [[ThisMode]] and, if it's `strict`, sets the *thisValue* to *thisArgument* directly without further logic (whereas if it weren't strict, it would replace `null` and `undefined` with the global object and do ToObject on any other values).

Comment: OrdinaryCallBindThis ( F, calleeContext, thisArgument ).    
test.call(obj, list).   

In this situation, F means test, calleeContext means obj, thisArgument means list. Is this right?

Comment: @李晓爽: No. *F* is `test` and *thisArgument* is `obj`. The *calleeContext* is the [execution context](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-execution-contexts) created by [[Call]]'s call to [PrepareForOrdinaryCall](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-prepareforordinarycall). (My link to [[Call]] above was wrong, btw, I've fixed it.)